# How to apply function complete() depending on a condition being fulfilled?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to apply the function `complete()` but only in those instances where a condition is fulfilled.

For example

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(
  group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
  value1 = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1,2),
  value2 = c(2,4,6,1,2,3,7,8,9),
  status = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)
)

df %>% complete(group, value1)
```

In the above example, I would like to do the last step, but have the extension carried out by `complete()` *only* in instances where variable "status" takes on value 1. Does anyone have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: At a guess, could you `filter` first before `complete`, then just join the opposite of your `filter` back on afterwards?

Comment: @rpickmans you should use `filter()` like `df %>% filter(status ==1 ) %>% complete(group, value1)`

Comment: @thelatemail I think something like that is right. But the issue is that I want to make sure that the filter is with respect to the largest value in either split of status, (i.e., irrespective of whether status is 1 or 0). I think with your solution I won't be able to capture this.

Comment: @RiteshPorwal Sorry - when I gave the example, I don't want to filter out those instances in which status==0, so I think thelatemail's suggestion is closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is surely a more elegant solution, but I believe this would work:

Data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(
  group = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
  value1 = c(0,1,2,3,0,1,0,1,2),
  value2 = c(2,4,6,1,2,3,7,8,9),
  status = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)
)
```

Code:

```
df %>%
  filter(status == 1) %>% 
  complete(group, value1) %>% 
  bind_rows(subset(df, status == 0))
```